# Определить id вложенного элемента при клике

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Код:

```
<div onClick={this.boxClick} id='divid'><audio src="1.mp3" id='5'></audio></div>
```

Определить id дива при клике можно так:
`boxClick(e) {alert(e.target.id);}`,
а как определить id вложенного элемента?

Код класса:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {}

  this.boxClick = this.boxClick.bind(this)
}
componentDidMount() {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  for (var x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) { divs[x].addEventListener('click', this.boxClick()); }
}

boxClick(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);//здесь нужен audio id
}

render() {

  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className='main'>
          <div className="box"><audio src="1.mp3" id='1'></audio></div>
          <div className="box"><audio src="2.mp3" id='2'></audio></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

События в DOM всплывают. Сначала происходит клик на самом глубоком элементе, по которому вы кликнули, потом на его родителе, на родителе родителя и так далее. `e.target` -- это ссылка на самый глубокий элемент, на котором произошло событие. Ссылка на элемент, на который повешен обработчик -- это `this`.

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
    alert(this.id);
})
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <div id="baz">
      click me
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите просто найти вложенный элемент, то воспользуйтесь `querySelector` (`querySelectorAll`). То есть найдите нужный вам элемент-потомок и получите его id.

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var children = this.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
        alert(children[i].id);
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <div id="baz">
      click me
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня несколько таких div-элементов

Answer (score 3):

1. Правильно писать не `id='divid'`, а `id="divid"`;
2. Так же атребут `onClick` необходимо использовать как можно реже.
   Правильно — вешать события.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.click');

elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log(this.children[0].id);
});
```

```html
<div class="click" id="divid">
  Click
  <audio src="1.mp3" id="5"></audio>
</div>
```

C использованием стрелочной функции (без `this`):

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.click');

elem.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(elem.children[0].id));
```

```html
<div class="click" id="divid">
  Click
  <audio src="1.mp3" id="5"></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Правильно писать не `id='divid',` а `id="divid";` - Почему? Кто запретил? По стандарту вообще можно написать `id=divid` и кто остановит?

Comment: @СергейМишин, можно (проверял на валидаторе).  Поймали, не правильно, а рекомендовано, например гуглом.

Comment: @СергейМишин https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Quotation_Marks

Comment: Спасибо. У меня функция-обработчик - это метод класса. Как в этом случае получить id?

Comment: @MyNick приведите код метода.

Comment: да он пустой, мне нужно будет использовать в нем значение id audio

Comment: @MyNick, приведите класс, я не понимаю в чём проблема.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96197/discussion-between-doox911-and-mynick).